# Best way to model large number of HTTP connections in Akka

Tags: java, multithreading, http, concurrency, akka

I am working with Akka using Java and looking for best way to model a large number of concurrent HTTP requests.  For more clarity, our system will have an event/message which will trigger the need to make a large number of "simultaneous" HTTP requests (consider maybe up to 1,200 at one time).

Comment: What did you try yet? (e.g. simply starting one actor for each request)

Comment: Yeah, like @thwiegan said: one actor per request might be a good start; also you need to choose carefully your HTTP client. I would recommend `akka-http` since we did something similar in the past, and for instance, `OkHttp` was giving us a hard time :/